# wrsmr command doesn't register my input in MSRs

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ubuntu-12.04, cpu-registers, msr

I have the following environment: `ubuntu 12.04` `kernel 3.2.0-29-generic-pae` all installed on `parallels version 11.0.1`. I have installed `msr-tools` using `apt-get` command.

My problem is when I execute the following command that is supposed write a value on msr register, nothing happens. It returns no error but as I use the `rdmsr`to read the very same register it shows me the previous value.

What am I missing here? Why doesn't my input get registered into the msr register when I run the wrmsr command? here is a summery of what I've tried

```
#rdmsr 0x198
1a0000000000

#wrmsr 0x198 08c1fe1d
#rdmsr 0x198
1a0000000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's simply due to having your linux installed on a virtual machine (in your case vmware workstation)

Since VMWare doesn't emulate the entire cpu registers and structure you're having this issue.

To resolve it though, you're simply gonna have to install your linux OS on a real machine.